# Show more information on out_of_range exceptions

Tags: c++, exception, libstdc++, libc++

In C++ there are a few `.at(index)` functions you can call that will through an `out_of_range` exception if your index/key is invalid. Unfortunately they don't give any information about what the key or valid range was:

> what():  _Map_base::at

Is there any way to opt in to more informative messages? I.e. `map.at(): key 432 does not exist` or `vector.at(): index 34 exceeds vector size of 20`.

Presumably this will depend on the C++ library I am using, so I am interested in answers for libc++ and libstd++. Maybe some kind of macro you define.

Comment: Yes, there's a way to get more context about the thrown exception: a debugger. That's what a debugger is for. All debuggers can automatically break for a thrown exception at which point the exact details of what's going on can be retrieved and inspected using the usual debugger tools.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik if I use `at` to validate user input, I dont want my customer to use a debugger to provide them a meaningful message ;)

Comment: In that case, just make sure that the index is valid. Rather than relying on a thrown exception, a user-entered index should be checked against `size()`. Problem solved.

Comment: Accessing containers out of range is generally considered to be programming error, regardless if incorrect index came from user input, data file or was calculated by program itself. So just tell to end user that this program contains a programming error when you catch that exception.

Comment: I don't know a way to update the message the library gives, but you could always catch the generic message and throw a more detail version like `try { map.at(something); } catch (const std::out_of_range& e) { throw std::out_of_range("updated message here"); }`.  You can then wrap that in a macro if you want to cut down on the boiler plate.

Comment: Re: "if I use `at` to validate user input" -- don't do that. `at` is a debugging aid, not a validation function. Validate user input when it comes in; make sure that it makes sense. Then you don't need `at` at all.

Comment: I've always felt that `at` was a misfeature. Especially when beginners write code like `for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i) { if (vec.at(i) != 0) vec.at(i) = vec.at(i) + 2; }`, with three entirely redundant range checks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at both the libc++ and libstdc++ source code. Unfortunately there are no macros that affect the exceptions they through at least for `vector` and `map`, although libstdc++ does actually show the relevant information for `vector::at()` by default!

```
      void
      _M_range_check(size_type __n) const
      {
    if (__n >= this->size())
      __throw_out_of_range_fmt(__N("vector::_M_range_check: __n "
                       "(which is %zu) >= this->size() "
                       "(which is %zu)"),
                   __n, this->size());
      }
```

I guess to be fair it is a bit trickier for maps since they key isn't necessary convertible to a string.